# Blank screen, cursor blinking on boot after install disruption

Tags: installation, cursor

I finished building a computer and started installing ubuntu when the power went out. Now, whenever I try to boot, absolutely nothing gets displayed except a black screen with a single blinking cursor on the screen. I have tried holding down shift upon boot, but none of the options can be selected. No keyboard buttons or commands work except for ctrl+Alt+Del which restarts everything and goes right back to the blinking cursor. I am completely lost at this point as to what to do.

Comment: Did you have an operating system on your computer before you tried to install Ubuntu? If you had Windows, what version of Windows did you have?

Comment: I did not have any operating system on before I tried installing. Everything was completely clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hard drive is hosed. Start over and reinstall Ubuntu again. Since you don't have a working operating system on your hard drive, you can use the whole hard drive for Ubuntu. If there is an option to replace the broken Ubuntu installation with Ubuntu, then choose that option.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling from the same bootable USB, but it does the exact same thing whether it has the USB plugged in or not. Would there happen to be another way to reinstall?

Comment: You can try checking the boot order in the BIOS setup. If the hard drive comes before USB-HDD in the boot sequence, then the BIOS will try to boot to the hard drive before the USB if it detects any OS on the hard drive. So change the boot sequence and make USB-HDD the first item in the boot sequence.